# Building a voltage adjuster circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, circuit-design, diy

I've been trying to build an op amp circuit that takes an analog signal from my electric guitar of around -1.5 to 1.5 V to a voltage level of 0 to 5 V, so that I can put it into the ADC of a microcontroller. I used [this resource](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf?ts=1603235676851&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to make my design specifically figure 3. I'm having trouble finding the voltage I need to power my op amps. I tried 0V and 5V and the signal is squashed and doesn't change at all. When I connect the VCC+ and VCC- to 5V and -5V, I'm getting a signal, but its centered around -1Vs. I'm using [uA741](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos094g/slos094g.pdf?ts=1603236596122&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) op amps.

- Vref = 5V
- R1 = 1 kohm
- R2 = 470 ohm
- Rg = 14.7 kohm
- Rf = 10 kohm

[image: Schematic]

Comment: You barely need an op-amp for this, you could just AC couple into an input biased at VRef/2 by some resistors.  You'd loose a tiny bit of dynamic range, but not much especially accounting for headroom.  5v suggests you have something like an ATmega which may have relatively high ADC input impedance, some recent parts it can be enough lower you would need a buffer amplifier even if you didn't have gain though.

Comment: You want to use that -5V not +5V for your Vref. That second stage inverts your reference voltage! That's all you need to do : 741 will work OK off +/-5V, even though it's old. And if you're feeding it into a microcontroller ADC (10 or 12 bit)  the 741's audio quality will be good enough.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This worked but my signal is still hovering around -10 mV -3V do I need to change the gain of the circuit?

Comment: Or the offset : R1 and R2.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using uA741 op amps.

There's your problem then.  That thing was obsolete in the 1980's.  The data sheet that I have for an LM741 lists an output voltage swing of \$\pm16\mathrm{V}\$ with input power rails of \$\pm20\mathrm{V}\$ -- and that's with a \$10\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ load resistor, so about a 15mA load current.  That means you need **four volts** of overhead just to drive 15mA out of the thing.

To do this with less supply voltage, you need a rail to rail op-amp, or you need a much bigger voltage supply -- if you carry on with the 741 theme, you'll need -5V and +10V supplies.  If you *do* carry on with the 741 theme, your next question will be "why does my audio sound so crappy?" because the 741 is not a good audio op-amp.

I would recommend that you scour the web for a guitar preamp circuit.  Take the output of that, and capacitively couple it to a voltage divider that rides at 2.5V.  Then either run that straight into your ADC, or buffer it with a unity-gain stage and run *that* into your ADC.

Comment: Thanks I just had these lying around from a lab that my professor gave us. He tried to get us to use vacuum tubes to build a fm transmitter, so I guess that makes sense. I also have a tl972 lying around would that probably work better for this solution right?

Comment: Do you want to solve your problem at hand, or screw around, learn lots, and eventually solve your problem at hand, maybe?  The TL972 has an input bias current of up to \$1\mu\mathrm{A}\$, and according to the website I checked on guitar output impedance, you want a preamp with an input impedance of up to \$1\mathrm{M}\Omega\$ -- those aren't compatible.  If you want success, now, do what smart engineers do and find something that works -- then shamelessly copy it.  Copy every detail you don't understand, right down to the part numbers.

Comment: I'll do some digging into guitar preamp circuits like you said. I would like to understand op amps more. I understand the basics, but I don't understand a lot of the different characteristics or types of op amps. What characteristics are the most important for op amp circuits?

Comment: All of them -- and no, I'm not being facetious.  For some circuits you can throw them together with any old op-amp, but for others some one characteristic or another will be a deal breaker.

Comment: When you're looking at circuits, try to find ones that come with articles written by the designer, that explain why they made the choices they did (so -- not Instructables or whatever).  Particularly with audio you have to take everything with a grain of salt, but you'll get an idea of the characteristics that matter.